# Google Adwords OAuth "error" : "invalid_client" exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, google-ads-api

I've inherited a google adwords project which is using OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications to connect to the google adwords API.

I'm falling over on the first hurdle; I've downloaded the following example project from github;

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dotnet-lib/tree/master/examples/AdWords/CSharp/OAuth

When I place all the details into the web.config as directed it doesn't work.
I've put in;

- the developer token
- the customer Id
- The refresh token.

This is all brand new to me, my understanding is that when using the refresh token the application should get a new access token and allow access to the API.

[image: screengrab of the sample app]

The above image shows the sample app interface, when I click on the "Get campaigns" link receive an exception message;

```
Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.AdsOAuthException was caught
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Failed to refresh access token.
{
  "error" : "invalid_client"
}
  Source=Google.Ads.Common
  StackTrace:
       at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.OAuth2ProviderForApplications.RefreshAccessTokenInOfflineMode()
       at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.OAuth2ProviderForApplications.RefreshAccessToken()
       at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.OAuth2ProviderBase.RefreshAccessTokenIfExpiring()
       at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.OAuth2ProviderForApplications.RefreshAccessTokenIfExpiring()
       at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.OAuth2ProviderBase.GetAuthHeader()
       at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.OAuth2ProviderForApplications.GetAuthHeader()
       at Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.Lib.AdWordsSoapClient.InitForCall(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
       at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.AdsSoapClient.MakeApiCall(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
       at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.AdsSoapClient.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
       at Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.v201601.CampaignService.get(Selector serviceSelector)
       at Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.Examples.CSharp.OAuth.Default.OnGetCampaignsButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) in c:\Adwords\examples\AdWords\CSharp\OAuth\Default.aspx.cs:line 130
  InnerException:
```

The application was using these credentials in a previous application, seemingly without issue.

I've searched high and low for an answer to this, the exception says that the access token can't be refreshed but the ambiguous reasoning doesn't help a great deal.

Could someone offer any further insight?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should set OAuth2ClientId  and OAuth2ClientSecret values in webconfig.

```
  <add key="OAuth2ClientId" value="your client id"/>
<add key="OAuth2ClientSecret" value="your client secret"/>
```

You can get clientid and client secret code from 
https://console.developers.google.com/project

Provide the OAuth2 client ID and secret. You can create one from
https://console.developers.google.com/project. See
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer
         for more details.